# Trying to automatically click a certain button on page load with JQuery script

Tags: jquery

so I'm trying to have a a script automatically select a certain button when I load a page. I've done it before with buttons that had ID's, but this button doesn't appear to have an ID and I can't figure out what to use as a selector. I'm obviously really new to this.

```
$("input[value=xyz]").click();
```

This is the code I've used before successfully, I basically had it automatically fill in all radio buttons of a certain type. Now I'm working with this:

```
<button class="category-button awsui-util-t-l">
    <sup class="category-hotkey">3</sup>
    "Good"
</button>
```

And I'm trying to figure out what to use as a selector to click this particular button. I've tried to use the text that is located in the button such as "Good" and "3" but I can't seem to figure out the proper way to locate those elements. This button is in a group of 4 other buttons and I want to select this one specifically. I've tried nonsense like

```
$("button:contains[text='Good']").click();
```

And other probably grammatically incorrect stuff because I don't really know how to use JQuery, but I was hoping someone could help me figure this out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Is the button inside an element with an id you can target?  You could select something like `$("#knownid button.category-button.awsui-util-t-l")` and get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the click handler and a trigger for that using the class perhaps:  I added a new class with border just to show it in action.

I also added a contains filter example in case you need that.

```js
$(".category-button.awsui-util-t-l")
  .on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('doneit');
  })
  .trigger("click");

// must contain something, filter those
$(".category-button.awsui-util-t-l")
  .filter(function() {
    return $.contains($(this)[0], $(".category-hotkey-new")[0]);
  })
  .on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('doneit-more');
  })
  .trigger("click");
```

```css
.doneit {
  border: solid purple 2px;
}

.doneit-more {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="category-button awsui-util-t-l">
    <sup class="category-hotkey">3</sup>
    "Good"
</button>

<button class="category-button awsui-util-t-l">
    <sup class="category-hotkey-new">3</sup>
    "Good"
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click based on text, you can use selector as follows:

```
$('button:contains("Good")').click()
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working on the page I want to use the script on. Where would I go from here?